# Python3 - Why calling a operator from a dict is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So I have these code:

```
def evaluate(expression):
    if any(not (c.isdigit() or c.isspace() or c in '(){}[]+-*/') for c in expression):
        return
    newexp = expression.split()
    stack = Stack()
    for i in newexp:
        if i in ')]}':
            arg2 = stack.pop()
            operator = stack.pop()
            arg1 = stack.pop()
            if stack.pop() not in '([{':
                return
            stack.push({'+': add}[operator](arg1,arg2))
        else:
            stack.push(i)    

    #checking
    while not stack.is_empty():
        print(stack.pop())

n = input('Input expression: ')
evaluate(n)
```

if I use

> '( 5 + 2 )'

as the input, the output will be

> 52

I supposed to get

> 7

as the answer.

Doing this will get `7`:

```
print({'+': add}['+'](5,2))
```

but isn't it actually the same? Can you guys tell me which part of my code is wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Because you're working with strings, not numbers.

Comment: oh yeah, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this change
`stack.push({'+': add}[operator](int(arg1),int(arg2)))`